# Build automatic diagramms of JSON structure

Tags: json, data-structures, diagram, diagramming

I'm searching service when I can build diagramms.

Example you can see here: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse333/12sp/assignments/hw2/hw2.html

Have a nice day and thank you!

Comment: For the record, software recommendation is off-topic on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is in case you are searching for web environment diagrams,
you can use:
[NVD3.js](http://nvd3.org/)
which is av simplified version of [D3.js](http://d3js.org/)

you can see thier examplese pages:
[NVD3.js examples](http://nvd3.org/examples/index.html)
[D3.js example](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)

D3.js is far more flexible but you have to learn more in order to use it. for me NVD3.js was just fine.

there is also: [charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) & [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) but I'm less know about them.

Another related lib: http://c3js.org/